# How to send client Call sid to newly transferred agent using Twilio node.js library without using Database

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on a conference call scenario and want to transfer live call from one agent to other agent. When I transfer the call is there any method that I could use to send the Conference Name, ConferenceSid and client Call Sid to new agent. as response.send() sends values to existing client. Is there any method we can use to send these parameters to new agent? The API used is as follows.

```
client.conferences(conferences.sid)
    .participants
    .create({
      from: '+183xxxxxxxxx',
      to: `client:${agentNumber}`
    })
    .then(participant => console.log(participant));
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking here. You are showing the request to add a new participant to a conference call, but talkiing about `response.send()` which I assume is in response to a webhook. What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: Actually my case scenario is cold transfer i.e. the agent 1 disconnects from conference as soon as agent 2 is added. Since agent 1 connected the call so he had client call sid and conference name with him at local storage. When I pass the call to agent2 I'm able to add the new agent to the conference using the above API, but want a method to send client callsid, conference room name to the newly added agent i.e. agent2 as soon as he connects to the conference. Therefore, asked the question is their any method twilio allows for that so that I could transfer the information to agent2.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In this cold transfer scenario you already have the conference sid, as you show in your code. So, to find the conference name you can [use the REST API to look it up](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference#fetch-a-conference-resource).

```
client.conferences(conference.sid)
  .fetch()
  .then(conference => console.log(conference.friendlyName));
```

You can also [fetch the conference participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant#read-multiple-participant-resources). One of the call sids will be the call you created to your agent and the other will be the caller that is already on the line.

```
client.conferences('CFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
  .participants
  .list()
  .then(participants => {
    participants.forEach(participant => console.log(participant.callSid));
  });
```

Using these two API calls you can get the information for your new agent.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I get these values as per described method. Now is there any method twilio provides so that i could send these values to new agent. I mean I want to provide these values i.e. client call sid, room name and conference sid to new agent which is a web client. What method/methods can be used to transfer these values to the agent.

Comment: Have you looked into using something like [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync) which allows you to share state in the cloud?